# Which one of the below options is correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

[image]

I think the option $(Q)$ is true since $O(Q/\{-1,1\})= 8/2 = 4 = 2^2$.
Since order is $p^2$ thus $(Q)$ option is true.
Can anyone suggest about option $(P)$?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(P)$ is wrong: there is only one normal subgroup $H$ of order $4$ in $S_4$, and $S_4/H\simeq S_3$. See [Show that $S_4/K \cong S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568422/show-that-s-4-k-cong-s-3/1568443#1568443).

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct about (Q).

As to (P), you should know there is a unique normal subgroup $V$ of order $4$ in $S_{4}$. This is a transitive subgroup, so $S_{4} = V T$, where $T$ is the stabilizer of $4$, say. But then $T \cong S_{3}$.