# Showing an Isomorphism between question group of $S_4$ and $D_6$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

I have a subgroup $N$ of $S_4$, where $ N = [1, (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3)] $
I need to explain whether quotient group $G/N$ is isomoprhic to either $C_6$ or $D_6$ (no proof required, just an explanation to why its isomorphic to one and not the other). Now i know its $D_6$ as N doesn't have a generator element and is not cyclic but this is a weak explanation, I can't spot any other differences.

Comment: what group is $G$?

Comment: Sorry, G is $S_4$

Comment: ah okay. Anyway you got your answer already! $C_6$ is cyclic wheres $D_6$ is not so $C_6\not\simeq D_6$.

Comment: That's not a weak answer, it's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: But the fact that $N$ is not cyclic does not imply that $G/N$ is not cyclic, so you won't get many marks for that explanation!

Comment: possible duplicate of [An epimorphism from $S_{4}$ to $S_{3}$ having the kernel isomorphic to Klein four-group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106777/an-epimorphism-from-s-4-to-s-3-having-the-kernel-isomorphic-to-klein-fou)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose there was a surjective homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_4\to C_6$ with $H$ as the kernel. What would the preimage of a generator of $C_6$ have to satisfy?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $S_4$ doesn't have any element of order $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $G/N\simeq C_6$. Then $G/N$ contains a unique, and therefore normal, subgroup of order 2. Let $H \le G$ be the pre-image of this group under the natural homomorphism $G \to G/N$. Then $H$ is a normal Sylow-2-subgroup of $G$ which contradicts the structure of $S_4$.