# deduce that $\frac{S_4}{V_4}$ is isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I have managed to do part i and ii. In part ii, the number of left cosets of H is 4.

I am stuck with part iii. I am guessing I will have to use first isomorphism theorem but not sure how.

$V_4$ is the potential kernel as it is normal subgroup  (part i)
But now i am not sure on what to do next.
Do I have to find homomorphism from $S_4$ to some group such that that group has a subgroup $S_3$? But then how do I show that this is actually isomorphic to S4/V4 ?

Thanks. I am confused about first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Andreas Caranti's answer is the way to do this the way part (ii) leads to part (iii). For different approached to (iii) see the questions listed as *related* on the sidebar. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/106777/11619) seems to be missing, so I add it this way. The same arguments have probably been written many times over in this site. This is a common exercise and comes with different sets of hints - all emphasizing slightly different aspects.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose 
$$ h_{1} V_{4} = h_{2} V_{4} ,$$
with $h_{1}, h_{2} \in H$.
Then
$h_{2} = h_{1} v$ for some $v \in V_{4}$. Therefore
$$
4 = 4 h_{2} = 4 h_{1} v = 4 v.
$$
But the only element $v \in V_{4}$ that fixes $4$ is $v = e$, so $h_{2} = h_{1} e = h_{1}$.

Now you know that there are $6$ distinct cosets $h V_{4}$, for $h \in H$. Since $\lvert S_{4} : V_{4} \rvert = 6$, all cosets of $V_{4}$ are of this form, and thus  $S_{4} = V_{4} H$. It follows (or you can check) that $V_{4} \cap H = \{ e \}$. Therefore
$$
\frac{S_{4}}{V_{4}} = \frac{V_{4} H}{V_{4}} \cong \frac{H}{V_{4} \cap H} = \frac{H}{\{ e \}} \cong H.
$$
Here I have used the [second isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative way to show $(iii)$;

$S_4/V_4$ is a group of order $6$ and there are two groups of order $6$, $S_3$ and $Z_6$.

But $S_4/V_4 \not \cong Z_6$ since $S_4$ has no elements of order $6$ or a multiple of $6\implies S_4/ V_4\cong S_3$.