# $S_4/H \simeq S_3$ where $H$ is a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, galois-theory, normal-subgroups

> Prove that the group of permutations of four symbols $S_4$ contains a normal
>   subgroup H such that the quotient group $S_4/H$ is isomorphic to the group of
>   permutations of three symbols $S_3$.

$S_4$ has order $24$. Any subgroup thus will have order $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12$ or $24$.

A normal subgroup is a union of conjugacy classes which in this case correspond to the cycle shapes as follows:

1. 6 of the form $(abcd)$
2. 8 of the form $(abc)(d)$
3. 3 of the form $(ab)(cd)$
4. 6 of the form $(ab)(c)(d)$
5. 1 identity element

If $S_4/H\simeq S_3$ with one of the above normal subgroups as $H$ then by Lagrange $|H|=\frac{|S_4|}{|S_3|}=4$ but there are no normal subgroups with this order.

Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: The union of conjugacy classes $3$ and $5$ forms a subgroup.

Comment: Why do you think there are no normal subgroups with this order? Think of groups of order 4, any group of order 4 is either isomorphic to $V_4$ or $C_4$, find subgroups of $S_4$ that are isomorphic to one of these two and check whether they are normal

Comment: Do also have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/106779/307187)

Answer (score 3):

1) Check that a *subgroup* $\;H\;$ of a group is a **normal** subgroup iff it is the (disjoint) union of conjugacy classes.

2) With (1), or directly,  check that $\;V:=\left\{\,(1),\,(12)(34),\,(13)(24)\,,\,(14)(23)\,\right\}\lhd S_4\;$

3) Take now the quotient group $\;S_4/V\;$ . By Lagrange's theorem, this group's order is six, so it is either $\;S_3\;$ or the cyclic group $\;C_6\;$ . In order to show it is actually the former it is enough to show there are two *different* elements of order two in the quotient (be sure you can justify this), and indeed:

$$(12)V\neq V\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\left((12) V\right)^2=\overline1=V\,,\,\,\text{and the same's true for}\;\;(13)V$$

Now, the above two elements are the same iff:

$$(12)V=(13)V\iff (12)^{-1}(13)\in V\iff (12)(13)=(132)\in V$$

and since $\;(132)\notin V\;$ we've finished.

Answer (score 0):

A normal subgroup, as you noted, is a union of conjugacy classes. It must also contain the identity element, which accounts for $1$ element of $H$. Do the sizes of any of the other conjugacy classes plus $1$ give you $4$?

---

Edit: Now that you know the correct subgroup, here's something to think about for proving $S_4/H\simeq S_3$. Note that every element of $S_4$ can be written as a product of transpositions. There are $6$ transpositions: $(12),(13),(14),(23),(24),(34)$. In the quotient, we have, for instance, $(12)(34)H=H$, so $(12)H=(34)H$. Similarly, $(13)H=(24)H$, and $(14)H=(23)H$. So in the quotient $S_4/H$ everything can be written as a product of $(12)H$, $(13)H$, and $(23)H$.

Now using that fact, can you define a surjective homomorphism $S_4\to S_3$ with kernel $H$? (Note that everything in $S_3$ is a product of $(12),(13),(23)$. Since $(12)H=(34)H$ in the quotient, your map should send $(12)$ and $(34)$ to the same place. Similarly with the other cosets that are equal.)

Comment: Oh ok, so could we let $H=\{e, (ab)(cd)\}$? This would have the required order $4$ but how can we prove that $S_4/H \simeq S_3$?

Comment: See the added details.

Comment: @amiz9 Why do you think your $\;H\;$ has order four? It has only two elements as far as I can see...

Comment: @Joanpemo I think I am confusing it all up

Comment: @Joanpemo I took $(ab)(cd)$ to mean all elements of that form, i.e., $(12)(34)$, $(13)(24)$, and $(14)(23)$.

Comment: @kccu Thank you. I didn't, and from his last comment I think neither the asker did.

Comment: @Joanpemo The OP wrote that there were $3$ elements of that form in the original question, which is why I assumed that. In any case, $H$ should definitely include all of those elements!

Comment: @kccu Indeed, I didn't see that. I think you may be right and that'swhat the asked meant, yet I he wrote after my first comment that he thought he was confusing it all. Hopefully things are clearer now.