# Homomorphism from the alternating group $A_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Well, my question is how to construct an explicit homomorphism from the alternating group $A_4$ onto $\mathbb{Z}_3$, since it is known that the quotient group $A_4/V\cong \mathbb{Z}_3$, $V$ being the Klein group, I would like to find such a homomorphism with kernel $V$.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you identify a subgroup of $A_4$ that is isomorphic to $V$?

Comment: You know that in general if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ there is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $G/H$ with kernel $H$. The _proof_ of that fact constructs an explicit homomorphism.

Comment: Use the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106777/11619) and restrict the homomorphism $f:S_4\to S_3$ to the subgroup $A_4$, when the image is automatically $A_3\simeq \Bbb{Z}_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's easy to build such a homomorphism by deciding what happens to each coset of $V$, the subgroup of double-transpositions (i.e. the only Klein group in $A_4$).  That being said, such a definition isn't particularly intuitive.

There are two such homomorphisms, I'll describe one of them geometrically.  Identify $A_4$ with the permutations of the corners of a square; label the corners $1,2,3,4$ clockwise.  Note that each element of $A_4$ is either a double-transposition, or fixes a corner and rotates the remaining elements.  For any $g \in A_4$, we define
$$
\phi(g) = \begin{cases}
0 & g \text{ is a double-transposition}\\
\\
1 & g \text{ fixes an odd number and rotates}\\
& \text{the remaining elements clockwise or }\\
& \text{fixes an even number and rotates the }\\
& \text{remaining elements ccw}\\
\\
2 &  g \text{ fixes an even number and rotates}\\
& \text{the remaining elements clockwise or }\\
& \text{fixes an odd number and rotates the }\\
& \text{remaining elements ccw}\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $\Bbb Z_3 = \{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: I suspect that there's a nicer interpretation here if we think of the corners as being corners of a tetrahedron rather than of a square.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I have tried this defining the function practically specifying how each element of each coset in $A_4/V$ is sent to $\mathbb{Z}_3$... I consider that this is not a "natural way" of doing this... there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Your Klein four group is $\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$.  Now use the canonical projection.

Note: there is another one, since there is a nontrivial automorphism of $\Bbb Z_3$, gotten by composition.