# Character table of S4

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, irreducible-representation

I am trying to understand the character table of $S_4$. I have obtained the trivial, signature and standard representations. The fourth one is the product of signature and standard.

[image]

Now for the last representation, I have tried two things.

1. I took the standard basis for $C$, defined $\pi(\sigma)e_i = e_{\sigma i}$. I took the trace of the  matrices as characters, but there it turned out that $\pi$ is just direct sum of trivial and standard representations.
2. I have read that I should take the normal subgroup corresponding to (12)(34). I don't know how to go about it. Can somebody explain?
   Any other method to determine the last representation is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: [There exists an epimorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106777/11619) allowing you to pull back irreducible reps of $S_3$ to $S_4$.

Comment: Also, when only one irreducible is missing from a character table, you can use orthogonality relations to figure it out.

Comment: If all you want is the last row of the character table, you can conclude the $e$ column has to be 2 since the sum of squares has to reach $|S_4| = 24$; and then the representation of $S_4$ acting on $\bigoplus_{\sigma \in S_4} \mathbb{C}$ (with total character 24,0,0,0,0) has to decompose into 1 copy each of the first and second, 3 copies each of the third and fourth, and 2 copies of the fifth.